# Concat ArrayList: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

Tags: azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-pipelines

I am getting an error while concatenating the array lists in powershell.

```
  For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
  {

    $filePath = $filePath.Replace("/", "\")
    $fileExt = $filePath.Split(".")[-1] 

     $Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath      $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$name -Encoding $EncodingType
     $OutputFileContent += $Content
     $FileObject = New-Object PSobject -Property @{
            Path = $filePath
            Extension = $fileExt
            Contents = $OutputFileContent 
        }


   $changeSet += $FileObject
  }
```

The last line is causing this issue.

```
   Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]     does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

  $changeSet += $FileObject

  CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], 
  ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Is your script running successfully locally?

Comment: What's $changeSet? How do you declare it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `PSObject` to an `ArrayList` with the `+` operator. Use the `Add` method of `ArrayList` to append items to the list.

```
$changeSet.Add($fileObject)
```

Comment: Still getting an error.
`this FileObject @{Contents=System.Object[]; Extension=pkb; Path=.\Package\TEST_PKG_I_LOOKUPS2.pkb}

 Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'add'.
At /Users//Downloads/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.136.1/Liquibase/_temp/63f184e0-db7e-4bbe-b130-8c2325d2b373.ps1:95 char:8
      $Changeset.add($fileObject)
 CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (add:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: Then `$changeSet` is not an `ArrayList`. Are you sure the code you posted is the code you're running?

Comment: Its not ArrayList I was testing with ArrayList. I updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

@gopal,

Use the Power of PowerShell. You can simply do below without defining $changes

```
$changes = For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
           {   

               $filePath = $filePath.Replace("/", "\")
               $fileExt = $filePath.Split(".")[-1] 

               $Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$name `
               -Encoding $EncodingType
               $OutputFileContent += $Content
               $FileObject = New-Object PSobject -Property @{
                                 Path = $filePath
                                 Extension = $fileExt
                                 Contents = $OutputFileContent 
                             }
           }
```